# using class weights with sklearn votingClassifier

Tags: scikit-learn, classification, ensemble-learning, imbalanced-data

I have an imbalance dataset for a classification problem. My target variable is binary and has two category. 
I implemented Random Forest and Logistic Regression by assigning class_weights as parameter.
When I fit data to random forest and logistic regression separately it works fine. But when I use Voting Classifier on random forest and logistic regression from sklearn.ensemble to fit on the data  it gives error `Class label no_payment not present.` I need to take ensemble of 3 or more models. I have check that this error is not because of naive_bayes implemented in the code.

My code:

```
rf_param = { 'class_weight': {'no_payment': 1, 'payment': 3},'criterion': 'gini', 'max_depth': 5, 'min_samples_leaf': 30, 'min_samples_split': 15, 'n_estimators': 100}
lr_param = {'C': 0.1,  'class_weight': {'no_payment': 1, 'payment': 3}, 'fit_intercept': False, 'penalty': 'l2'}

rf = ensemble.RandomForestClassifier(**rf_param)
lr = linear_model.LogisticRegression(**lr_param)
nb = naive_bayes.MultinomialNB(alpha=0.0, class_prior=None, fit_prior=False)


rf.fit(train_x, train_y)
lr.fit(train_x, train_y)
nb.fit(train_x, train_y)

model = ensemble.VotingClassifier(estimators=[('rf', rf), ('lr', lr), ('nb',nb)], voting='hard'
                                 ,weights = [2,2,1])
model.fit(train_x, train_y)

predictions = model.predict(valid_x)
```

This code runs perfectly if I remove `class_weight` from parameter list.

Below is complete error message.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-e05cd516f347> in <module>()
     15                                  )
     16 
---> 17 model.fit(train_x, train_y)
     18 
     19 predictions = model.predict(valid_x)

/home/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/_voting.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    220         transformed_y = self.le_.transform(y)
    221 
--> 222         return super().fit(X, transformed_y, sample_weight)
    223 
    224     def predict(self, X):

/home/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/_voting.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
     66                 delayed(_parallel_fit_estimator)(clone(clf), X, y,
     67                                                  sample_weight=sample_weight)
---> 68                 for clf in clfs if clf not in (None, 'drop')
     69             )
     70 

/home/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
   1002             # remaining jobs.
   1003             self._iterating = False
-> 1004             if self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
   1005                 self._iterating = self._original_iterator is not None
   1006 

/home/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    833                 return False
    834             else:
--> 835                 self._dispatch(tasks)
    836                 return True
    837 

/home/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in _dispatch(self, batch)
    752         with self._lock:
    753             job_idx = len(self._jobs)
--> 754             job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
    755             # A job can complete so quickly than its callback is
    756             # called before we get here, causing self._jobs to

/home/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py in apply_async(self, func, callback)
    207     def apply_async(self, func, callback=None):
    208         """Schedule a func to be run"""
--> 209         result = ImmediateResult(func)
    210         if callback:
    211             callback(result)

/home/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py in __init__(self, batch)
    588         # Don't delay the application, to avoid keeping the input
    589         # arguments in memory
--> 590         self.results = batch()
    591 
    592     def get(self):

/home/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self)
    254         with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
    255             return [func(*args, **kwargs)
--> 256                     for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    257 
    258     def __len__(self):

/home/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    254         with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
    255             return [func(*args, **kwargs)
--> 256                     for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    257 
    258     def __len__(self):

/home/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/_base.py in _parallel_fit_estimator(estimator, X, y, sample_weight)
     34             raise
     35     else:
---> 36         estimator.fit(X, y)
     37     return estimator
     38 

/home/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/_forest.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    319         self.n_outputs_ = y.shape[1]
    320 
--> 321         y, expanded_class_weight = self._validate_y_class_weight(y)
    322 
    323         if getattr(y, "dtype", None) != DOUBLE or not y.flags.contiguous:

/home/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/_forest.py in _validate_y_class_weight(self, y)
    585                     class_weight = self.class_weight
    586                 expanded_class_weight = compute_sample_weight(class_weight,
--> 587                                                               y_original)
    588 
    589         return y, expanded_class_weight

/home/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/class_weight.py in compute_sample_weight(class_weight, y, indices)
    161             weight_k = compute_class_weight(class_weight_k,
    162                                             classes_full,
--> 163                                             y_full)
    164 
    165         weight_k = weight_k[np.searchsorted(classes_full, y_full)]

/home/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/class_weight.py in compute_class_weight(class_weight, classes, y)
     63             i = np.searchsorted(classes, c)
     64             if i >= len(classes) or classes[i] != c:
---> 65                 raise ValueError("Class label {} not present.".format(c))
     66             else:
     67                 weight[i] = class_weight[c]

ValueError: Class label no_payment not present.
```

Comment: The error message is very clear here: you are assigning weights to a class "no_payment" which doesn't exist in your data..

Comment: But that class exists in data. Rf.fit, lr.fit and nb.fit works perfectly. This error is returned when class weighted models are used in ensemble. If I remove class_weight parameter from Rf and lr, the whole script executes perfectly.

Comment: You are right I was able to replicate your error now. This is indeed a bit strange

Comment: occurring to me too. it's weird that it doesn't work in ensemble learning.